# Managing contents of requirements.txt for a Python virtual environment

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv, requirements.txt

So I am creating a brand new Flask app from scratch. As all good developers do, my first step was to create a virtual environment.

The first thing I install in the virtual environment is `Flask==0.11.1`. Flask installs its following dependencies:

> - click==6.6
> - itsdangerous==0.24
> - Jinja2==2.8
> - MarkupSafe==0.23
> - Werkzeug==0.11.11
> - wheel==0.24.0

Now, I create a **requirements.txt** to ensure everyone cloning the repository has the same version of the libraries. However, my dilemma is this:

- Do I mention each of the Flask dependencies in the **requirements.txt** along with the version numbers 
   OR
- Do I just mention the exact Flask version number in the **requirements.txt** and hope that when they do a **pip install requirements.txt**, Flask will take care of the dependency management and they will download the right versions of the dependent libraries

Comment: Take a look at the `pip-compile` command in [pip-tools](https://github.com/nvie/pip-tools/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @dirn..this is really nice..thanks for that..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both approaches are valid and work. But there is a little difference. When you enter all the dependencies in the `requirements.txt` you will be able to pin the versions of them. If you leave them out, there might be a later update and if Flask has something like `Werkzeug>=0.11` in its dependencies, you will get a newer version of Werkzeug installed.

So it comes down to updates vs. defined environment. Whatever suits you better.

Answer (score 37):

One good thing here is you are using virtualenv, which will make your task very easy.

1. Activate virtualenv (`$source path_to_virtualenv/bin/activate`)
2. Go to your project root directory
3. Get all the packages along with dependencies in requirements.txt

   ```
   pip freeze > requirements.txt
   ```
4. You don't have to worry about anything else apart from making sure next person installs the requirements recursively by following command

   ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
   ```

Answer (score 7):

You can (from your active virtual environment) do the following

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

which'll automatically take care of all libraries/modules available in your project.

The next developer would only have to issue:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to see what packages you have installed then just do 
`pip freeze`.

but if you want all these packages in your requirement.txt, then do 

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`